# Return a completable in RxSwift without using a create block

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a Completable being returned from a simple function. 
This is not an async call, so I just need to return a succcessful completion or error depending on a conditional (using Rx here so I can tie into other Rx usages):

```
func exampleFunc() -> Completable {
    if successful {
        return Completable.just() // What to do here???
    } else {
        return Completable.error(SomeErrorType.someError)
    }
}
```

The error case works pretty easily, but am having a block on how to just return a successful completable (without needing to `.create()` it).

I was thinking I just need to use Completable's `.just()` or `.never()`, but `just` is requiring a parameter, and `never` doesn't seem to trigger the completion event.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`.empty()` is the operator I was looking for!

Turns out, I had mixed up the implementations of `.never()` and `.empty()` in my head!

- `.never()` emits no items and **does NOT** terminate
- `.empty()` emits no items but **does** terminate normally

So, the example code above works like this:

```
func exampleFunc() -> Completable {
    if successful {
        return Completable.empty()
    } else {
        return Completable.error(SomeErrorType.someError)
    }
}
```

Here is the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html) on empty/throw/never operators.

Answer (score 0):

I would be more inclined to do the following:

```
func example() throws {
    // do something
    if !successful {
        throw SomeErrorType.someError
    }
}
```

Then in order to tie it into other Rx code, I would just use `map` as in:

```
myObservable.map { try example() }
```

But then, mapping over a Completable doesn't work because map's closure only gets called on next events. :-(

I tend to avoid Completable for this very reason, it doesn't seem to play well with other observables. I prefer to use `Observable<Void>` and send an empty event before the completed...

Something like this:

```
let chain = Observable<Void>.just()
let foo = chain.map { try example() }
foo.subscribe { event in print(event) }
```

Comment: Good points. I am trying to occasionally use traits so I understand their use cases and limitations better - noticed concat and merge operators had been added to Completable in [v3.5.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) so hoping they get easier to integrate with other flows as more operators are added!